# Subtracting 2000 from Range of values

Tags: excel

I have a column which contains following values:

```
646-900
634-645
611-633
589-610
and so on
```

I want to first reverse the range in each row and then subtract the values from 2000 so that it now becomes

```
1100-1354
1355-1366
1367-1389
1390-1411
```

How can I write the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
=(2000-MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))&"-"&(2000-LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))
```

`FIND("-",A1)` gets the position of the `-` for the `MID` and `LEFT` functions. Using `-1` or `+1` allows to get the position of where to stop in case of `LEFT` and where to start in case of the `MID` respectively. The `MID` gets the right part of the text while `LEFT` gets the left part of the text.

Subtract the result from 2000 and concatenate everything back with `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different way to do it.  If your 2000 value might change put it in another cell and reference it like this: (put formula in C2 and drag down, put 2000 in C1)

```
=($C$1-RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2))) & "-" & $C$1-LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. parse the text in your cells, `FIND()` the position of the "-" char
2. extract each side of the range, use `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions.
3. transform to a `VALUE()` the returned text of each side of the range
4. subtract from 2000 each value
5. finally concatenate the results in reverted order with the `&` operator (remember to insert a "-" between them).

Comment: =2000-MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,100)&"-"&2000-LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)

Comment: I know, thanks. Just trying to motivate OP to try by herself.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do text manipulation on the ranges to obtain the lower bound and upper bound, perform the subtraction, and then concatenate to your new range. You can do all of this with the functions [`LEFT()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/left-leftb-functions-HP005209153.aspx), [`RIGHT()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/right-rightb-functions-HP010342854.aspx) and [`FIND()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/find-findb-functions-HP010342526.aspx).

To get the lower bound of the string in cell A1:

```
LEFT(A1, FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

To get the upper bound of the string in cell A1:

```
RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-", A1))
```

You can simply subtract these from 2000 to get the **new** bounds:

```
lower: 2000-RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-", A1))

and

upper: 2000-LEFT(A1, FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

You can now create a new range:

[image: Excel Table]

Where:

```
D2=B2&"-"&C2
```